# What is FROM_TZ oracle equivalent in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to convert `Trunc((FROM_TZ (TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-14','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'GMT') AT TIME ZONE 'PST'),'dd')` from Oracle to Snowflake.
Could anyone please help me with that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a script in Snowflake that gives you the exact same result as the statement you have provided, here is what you can do.

```
select day(convert_timezone('GMT','America/Los_Angeles',TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-04-14')::varchar));
```